# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel 5 when calling POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, put

I'm new to Laravel, I'm trying to update a record in my user table but I get this `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, I've tried everything but nothing has worked.

UsersController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Users;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = Users::all();
        return view('admin.users',compact('users'));
    }

    public function block(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Users::find($request->id);
        $user->blocked = 1;
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->action('UsersController@index'); 
    }
}
```

route.php

```
Route::get('/admin/users', 'UsersController@index');
Route::post('/admin/users/block',  'UsersController@block');
```

---

Until `$user->blocked = 1;` everything's well .

UPDATE 
I'm accessing the controller from this jQuery method

```
$("#valdiate-user-block").click(function(){
    var data = {
        id: 2
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "block",
        type:"POST",
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },error:function(){ 
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    }); //end of ajax
    });
```

i didn't mention it because i localized the error, when I access the controller from the root i get the error and when accessing it from jQuery I get

```
POST http://localhost:1303/admin/users/block 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please help me i'm stacked !!

Comment: What's the URL that you're accessing when you get that exception? And how do you access that URL?

Comment: Could you please show a form which sends a request?

Comment: I'm accessing the controller from an ajax request, I didn't mention it because i tried it manually to localize the error, i'll add it

Comment: Usually `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` indicates a CORS error, but your browser also returns it for 500 errors (which is really annoying honestly). Are you positive that your ajax request is triggering the `block` method? Like if you comment out all the code in that function and just return the string 'test', does your ajax function get the word 'test' back in its data or do you still have the error?

Comment: @AndyNoelker all the code is there, the ajax function is fine. when i add 'dd($user->toArray())' after '$user->blocked = 1;' I get a result and it's fine with all the data thar i need, but when it try to save it i get the 500 error

Comment: Can you change your line where you find your user to `$user = Users::find($request->input('id'));` and let me know if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it :)

i addedd `public $timestamps = false;`
in the Users class

and i deletet the type from the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
url: "users/block/",
data: data,
success:function(data){
alert(data);
},error:function(){ 
alert("error!!!!");
}
```

Thanx for your help :)

Comment: If timestamps were causing your problem, then you shouldn't have to do `Route::any`. Your code now just does a GET request for an update, which really is not great, and it also means that the `/admin/users/block` route cannot do anything else. You should probably be just fine with adding the `public $timestamps = false;` to your model and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want update you have to use `PATCH` consider on that and in your method

```
public function block(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['blocked'] = 1;
        $user->update($input);

        return redirect()->action('UsersController@index'); 
    }
```

if you want use `POST` then do like this

```
public function block(Request $request)
        {
            $input = $request->all();
            $input['blocked'] = 1;
            User::create( $input );
            return redirect()->action('UsersController@index'); 
        }
```

Comment: I want to update a user record so i can't add do      create     i think !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using below two lines:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests; // seems this one also incorrect to me (Requests?)(Request !)
```

Simply use below and check:

```
use Request;
```

Your updated code will be:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Users;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

    class UsersController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $users = Users::all();
            return view('admin.users',compact('users'));
        }

        public function block(){

            $inputData = Input::all(); // Reads all input array
            $your_id=   $inputData['id'];
            $user->blocked = 1;
            $user->save();

            return redirect()->action('UsersController@index');

        }
    }
```

Comment: i'm getting the same result

Comment: Why you are using this one (Request $request), First remove this one and 
try this line
$inputData = Input::all(); // Reads all input array

Comment: @VijaySaiChaudary The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is thrown when the HTTP verb of the request (GET, POST, PUT, etc) and the URL path, do not match a route definition. It has nothing to do with the namespace or usage of the `Request` class.